# set Title conditionally (Angular)

Tags: angular, binding, title

I need to set `title=""` only if my conditions is true if no there should be no `title` at all.
So, only if `property.propertyKey === 'birthday'` the `title` should get `birthday` value.

```
<div
  *ngFor="let property of visibleCandidateProperties"
  [title]="property.propertyKey === 'birthday' ? birthday">

  {{candidate[property.propertyKey]}}
</div>
```

In code above it doesn't work 'cause need to add some `: false` condition.
How can I rewrite it?
(Maybe it'd be even better to rewrite in `.ts` file, not `.html`, but still don't get how to do it)

Would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?

```html
<div
  *ngFor="let property of visibleCandidateProperties"
  [title]="property.propertyKey === 'birthday' ? birthday : ''">

  {{candidate[property.propertyKey]}}
</div>
```

Comment: I use `visibleCandidateProperties` to show the whole list of data (not only a birthday) in line `{{candidate[property.propertyKey]}}`. And only in case when `propertyKey === 'birthday'` I want to set a specific value to `title`. This filter will impact on that.